# (Mis)understanding Git branches and checkout

Tags: git

I have a branch, `v5`, and I create a new branch, `v6`, to test a new feature.  I make some changes to a few files and add some files before committing changes into the branch.
When I checkout the `v5` branch, the changes to the common files were 'rolled back' to `v5` as I expected, but the new files that I thought were specific to `v6` are now part of `v5`.  Why?

Comment: What does `git status` say?  Are you sure you committed the files in v6, or are they just sitting in your working copy?

Comment: Also: get gitg (Linux) or gitx (Mac). It's indispensable for visualizing your branch structure.

Comment: For [tag:git] questions of this form, it's helpful to produce a test case in the form of copy-pasteable shell commands that will reproduce your problem, otherwise it's hard to tell what exactly you mean with your description. (By reproduce the problem, I don't mean reproducing the whole state of your source tree, just create a new repo with a bunch of dummy data.)

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you didn't do "git add" to the new files before you did your commit on branch `v6`. They're still untracked, and git will just leave them lying around as you switch branches.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have done "git add" and "git commit" on branch v6, on checkout of branch v5, add files will disappear.

In case of **windows** open files doesn't get removed. They will remain as new files.

Files will get removed from index but will remain in working directory. If you want remove them from work tree try "git clean -xfd" and that time no file should be open.